# Check column's property "sortable". ExtReact

Tags: extjs, jsx

I have a grid with CheckColumn

```
<CheckColumn 
    dataIndex="check" 
    minWidth="auto"
/>
```

Default, CheckColumn is sortable, but when I try to make it nonsortable

```
<CheckColumn 
    dataIndex="check" 
    minWidth="auto"
    sortable=false
/>
```

I get this error:

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text (47:26)

  45 |                  dataIndex="check" 
  46 |                  minWidth="auto"
> 47 |                  sortable=false
     |                           ^
  48 |                 />
```

Comment: Try giving false inside quote.

Comment: @Tejas, I tried, it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this problem with {}

```
<CheckColumn 
    dataIndex="check" 
    minWidth="auto"
    sortable={false}
/>
```